# How to handle the json convert object in python

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have a JSON file which I converted in the python object using json.load() function.I want the output to be dict or list but its a string.

PS: The data I could not share because its a production data.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Please post some code / examples of your issue.

Comment: You'll have to provide source code and your json structure, be it with censored values or similar structure.

Answer (score 0):

you mean you have file is myJsonfile.json right ?
and you want to load them into python?

you can using like this

```
import json
file = open('myjsonfile.json','r')
jsonfile = json.load(file)
```

to check data it's was python now call

```
jsonfile
```

[image: my code]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Actually, I have a JSON file which I converted in the python object using load function what you have mentioned above.
The output what I getting that is a string. I want it to be a dict or list.

Comment: can you share mock up data of your json file.
I think it about you json file. if you got string like "{'hahaha':'what what that'}" maybe your can json.load() agian

Answer (score 0):

to change from a string to dict/list use `json.loads()`

So what every your stored string is, in the example below I called is `jsonStr`:

```
jsonStr = '''{"file_type": "json" , "data_type": "str"}'''


jsonObj = json.loads(jsonStr)
```

**Output:**

```
print (jsonObj)
{'file_type': 'json', 'data_type': 'str'}

print (type(jsonObj))
<class 'dict'>
```